# How to pass a JS variable from my client to an Express server?

Tags: node.js

How to pass a JS variable from my client to an Express server?
I want to take a variable that has info stored in it and use it in server side code in node.

Comment: AJAX. I can use uppercase too.

Comment: @nicovank ME TOO, BUT EDITING IS A MUCH BETTER OPTION

Answer (score 2):

You should use AJAX to send variables from client to server :

First, create a route where you'll handle the data :

```
router.post('/ajaxRoute', (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)  //your variables are here.
    res.status(200).json({msg:'OK'});

});
```

Then on your client, make a call to that route, sending your variables.

With jQuery :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/ajaxRoute",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json',
    data : yourdata,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.msg); // 'OK'
    },
});
```